# Multiple Instances objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, ios4

I am currently trying to set a UIImageView from a classB into classA.

But it seems that when i put a break point on the use of the UIImageView in classA it has not been set.

The code i am using is :-

```
rfshooterAppDelegate *delegate = (rfshooterAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
rfshooterViewController *controller = delegate.viewController;

[controller.hsvImage setImage:[self UIImageFromIplImage:hsv]];
```

Can anybody tell me what I could be doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell much from this small snippet. A couple things to try.

1) In the debugger, make sure controller is not null.
2) Make sure you get something back from [self UIImageFromIplImage:hsv]
3) Make sure hsvImage is not null.
4) Is hsvImage connected to the correct IBOutlet in Interface Builder?

Comment: OK thank you i will check those as soon as i get back to my mac, in the meantime, as regards to the snippet i left, does is it look right as regards to pointing to the same instance of an object instead of creating a new 1, i am new to objective-c you see and i am not used to the syntax

Comment: Picciano, if you come back to read this just want to thank you for your input. Originally the UIImageView I had set was an IBOutlet but i was not linking it the Interface Builder so I removed that, then i broke the code up abit to aid debugging and it seems to have transferred data between the classes correctly, which is good news, only problem now is that the image being displayed is black but that is another issue all together so thanks for your help.